# ADO equivalent to querying TFS in SQL?

Tags: tfs, ado

In a previous incarnation I was able to query the TFS Data Warehouse using SQL, which gave me the ability to generate much more sophisticated queries than the TFS query editor and WIQL provided.

I've recently started working in ADO instead of TFS, and I'm wondering if ADO provides any equivalent kind of querying capability on the back end, as opposed to the limited capability that the ADO query editor and WIQL offer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Analytics Views and Power BI to get way more information than before about Work Items in your instance.  You do get Analytics view in Build/Release/Tests as well, but you can't get them from Power BI.

[Analytics Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-are-analytics-views?view=azure-devops)